# Implementing a factory via the invoke() function of a companion object at the top of a sealed hierarchy

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, companion-object, kotlin-companion, kotlin-sealed

Consider I have a `sealed` type hierarchy in *Kotlin*, i.e. I'm the only one who controls how exactly a particular interface is implemented and how may implementations it has:

```kotlin
sealed interface Foo {
    val state: Int

    fun doSmth()
}
```

Now, there goes an implementation which I'd rather not expose to the clients of my API, hence marking it as `internal`:

```kotlin
internal data class FooImpl internal constructor(override val state: Int) : Foo {
    override fun doSmth() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now I need to implement a *factory*, and I do so directly in the `companion object` of my interface:

```kotlin
sealed interface Foo {
    // ...

    companion object Factory {
        operator fun invoke(state: Int): Foo = FooImpl(state)
    }
}
```

My clients will be instantiating the interface like this, knowing nothing about the actual implementation:

```kotlin
val foo: Foo = Foo(42)
```

Now, despite this code may look like a clever idea, the question is: what disadvantages it may have?

I've searched [*JetBrains*](https://github.com/JetBrains/) repositories at *GitHub*, and despite I did find several matches, their number is few. I'm wondering whether the above code is a known anti-pattern.

Comment: "what disadvantages it may have?" Compared to what? You should also give more context to narrow the question down. What kind of disadvantages are you looking for here? A "disadvantage" in one situation could be an advantage in another situation.

Comment: @Sweeper, thank you for your response. I'm looking for feedback purely from the OOP perspective -- like, exactly as I said, whether I've run into a known anti-pattern. Speaking of similar examples, [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), while being popular among C++ programmers, is an arguable technique in the Java world, and the original [DCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) pattern (w/o `volatile`), has proven broken despite it seemed clever in the 1st place.

Comment: Looks like an excellent pattern to me. Only problem I can see is that you won't be able to stub the instantiation call if you need to for testing purposes (as you would with a traditional Factory) but that may not be necessary in your case.